# Excel VBA: Checkbox element and How to count list elements

Tags: list, vba, excel, checkbox

I have created a listbox using activex controls. I want to have the list be populated given a range of cells in the condition that the checkbox has been clicked and it is empty at the time of being clicked. Also, I would like to clear out the list once the checkbox is unchecked (the line of code for this is wrong, please rectify):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1 = True  Then
        Listbox1.List = Range("C32:C33").Value
    ElseIf Check_Box1 = False Then
        Listbox1.List = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Additionally, is there a function to count the number of elements in a given listbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like below:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Me.CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        ListBox1.ListFillRange = "=A1:A4"
    Else
        ListBox1.ListFillRange = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This works, except it makes the ListBox smaller and smaller as I check and uncheck the CheckBox. Logically it seems fine, but I wonder why it is doing this.

Comment: I figured it out. The ListBox stopped becoming smaller and smaller when I opened the properties window and changed the integral height from "True" to "False". I have found the solution, but it still doesn't make sense why it would do that.

Comment: @Kmanchel I didn't have the same issue in my test case, so it's difficult for me to assist. One option is to code the `ListBox` height so that it expands to the appropriate height on click: `ListBox1.Height = 200` for example